# jQuery datepicker get month and year shown not current

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to get the "shown" month and year after hitting the "next" and "previous" links on the left and right of the date picker header.

Currently I'm using to get the month:

```
var selectedMonth = $('#calendar').datepicker('getDate').getMonth() + 1;
```

but it only returns the current month, not the shown month that comes with clicking "next" or "prev".

EDIT

I added the `onChangeMonthYear` option with the datepicker in the function i have

```
function getDates() {
var selectedMonth = $('.ui-datepicker-month').text();
var selectedYear = $('.ui-datepicker-year').text();
}
```

still this just states the current date.

EDITED Again

the above worked just needed to set a delay :]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$.datepicker('getDate')` only returns the selected date of the datepicker, not the month that is currently being shown.

What you're looking for is to bind a function to `onChangeMonthYear`.  [Docs here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onChangeMonthYear)

Example:

```
$('#calendar').datepicker('option', 'onChangeMonthYear', function(year, month) { var selectedMonth = month })
```

Comment: I seem to be getting `undefined` for "selectedMonth" and I'm creating the var outside of the function. Am i just approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: The year/month actually needs to be changed for this function to fire.