# jquery UI Datepicker fails to update month or year -- must select date

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Datepicker selection does not change the year or month unless the user selects a date. Looking for month/year to update even if date is not selected:

```
<input class="childdob dateinput datepickers hasDatepicker valid" 
placeholder="Date of Birth*" name="child_dob[0]" type="text">


$(function() {

        $('form').on('focus', '.datepickers', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
                 $(this).datepicker( {
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: '1990:+0',
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y',
                    constrainInput: false
                }).datepicker('show');
        });

    });
```

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044668/jquery-datepicker-get-month-and-year-shown-not-current.  You would need to bind a function to `onChangeMonthYear`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example that demonstrates updating the selected month and year when the month/year dropdown menus are changed or the month arrows are clicked without a date being directly selected. It arbitrarily sets the day to the 1st of each month, so you would need to modify if you wanted that to persist after a day has been selected.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepickers").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1990:+0',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    constrainInput: false,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month) {
      var selectedMonth = month;
      var selectedYear = year;
      $(this).datepicker("setDate", month + "/01/" + year);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepickers"></p>
```

Comment: When I use my previous function, the month default to '6' and the year '23' on any selection: ` $('form').on('focus', '.datepickers', function(event){`

Comment: I changed `dateFormat: 'mm/dd/y'` to `dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'` to get it to match up with the returned year value of `onChangeMonthYear`.  If you prefer your format, you could re-format the value in the `onChangeMonthYear` function I provided.  This is likely the issue, but let me know if you have lingering problems.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[Sebastian Barth's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831243/451893) works just fine, but if you are using a different date format, it can be a little picky about the format you use in the `datepicker('setDate',xxx)` method, and behaves strangely if you don't get it exactly right. So better to be 'DRY' about the format and specify it in just one place.

Also datepicker itself handles date preservation when changing months so no need to do the calculations of the number of days in the month.

So here's a furthe improved version of Sebastian Barth's improved version!

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepickers").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    numberOfMonths:3,
    defaultDate:'+1w',
    maxDate:new Date(),
    yearRange: '1990:+0',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy, M d',
    constrainInput: false,
    onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
      var format = inst.settings.dateFormat
      var selectedDate = new Date(inst.selectedYear,inst.selectedMonth,inst.selectedDay)
      var date = $.datepicker.formatDate(format, selectedDate);
      $(this).datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepickers"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

**This version preserves the day of the month.**
It is an improved version of the answer of [emshore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47359150/jquery-ui-datepicker-fails-to-update-month-or-year-must-select-date/47359751#47359751):

```js
$(function() {
  $(".datepickers").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '1990:+0',
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
    constrainInput: false,
    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month) {
      var $datepicker = jQuery(this);
      var date = new Date($datepicker.datepicker("getDate"));
      var lastDayOfMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
      var preservedDay = Math.min(lastDayOfMonth, Math.max(1, date.getDate()));
      $datepicker.datepicker("setDate", month + "/" + preservedDay + "/" + year);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<p>Date: <input type="text" class="datepickers"></p>
```